# PS script to show lines with multiple specific keywords in log file

Tags: powershell

I need to have a script that will grab specific lines within the txt log file and output them on the screen. I am able to grab the lines containing either of the keywords, but I need it to grab the lines with both of the keywords.

I have been trying to use get-content or search-string to get the lines within the log file, but they only grab the lines with either of the 2 words, rather than the string with both of the keywords within it.

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\Guys\Desktop\Logs\split\disk*.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "ID|USER"){
       Write-Host $_
    }
}
```

```
Select-String -Path "C:\Users\Guys\Desktop\Logs\split\disk*.txt" -Pattern 'ID|USER'
```

These only ouput lines with `ID` or `USER`

I have also had run `$_ -match "ID" -And "USER"` and it does the same.

I need the script to output the lines with both the keywords in it, not separately.

Comment: `$_ -match "ID" -and "USER"` won't do what you want. `$_ -match "ID" -and $_ -match "USER"` will. As for using `Select-String`: do the keywords appear in a particular order?

Comment: if($_ -like "\*ID\*" -and $_ -like "\*USER\*")

Comment: Both of the suggestions worked well. Thank you.